# How to iterate over positional parameters in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

Where am I going wrong?

I have some files as follows:

```
filename_tau.txt
filename_xhpl.txt
filename_fft.txt
filename_PMB_MPI.txt
filename_mpi_tile_io.txt
```

I pass `tau`, `xhpl`, `fft`, `mpi_tile_io` and `PMB_MPI` as positional parameters to script as follows:

```
./script.sh tau xhpl mpi_tile_io fft PMB_MPI
```

I want grep to search inside a loop, first searching tau, xhpl and so on..

```
point=$1     #initially points to first parameter
i="0"
while [$i -le 4]
do
  grep "$str" ${filename}${point}.txt
  i=$[$i+1]
  point=$i     #increment count to point to next positional parameter
done
```

Comment: bash script .. sorry i forgot to mention it

Comment: remember to put things like that into the tags, it makes the question easier to find for your target audience, ie. the people who have filtered out bash scripts as an interesting tag.

Comment: Please keep the code formated as **code** - it'll be a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set up your for loop like this.  With this syntax, the loop iterates over the positional parameters, assigning each one to 'point' in turn.

```bash
for point; do
  grep "$str" ${filename}${point}.txt 
done
```

As explained in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#index-for) this is a shorthand syntax, and this snippet is equivalent to:

```bash
for point in "$@"; do
  grep "$str" ${filename}${point}.txt 
done
```

Comment: I suggest quotes around the filename argument to avoid trouble with spaces.

Comment: Aaron, good point.  I copy/pasted that line from the question without editing it.  Dennis, that's not correct.  There's no need to assign to point directly.  See the "Compound Commands" section of the Bash manual for all the  details.

Answer (score 5):

There is more than one way to do this and, while I would use `shift`, here's another for variety. It uses Bash's indirection feature:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++))
do
    grep "$str" ${filename}${!i}.txt
done
```

One advantage to this method is that you could start and stop your loop anywhere. Assuming you've validated the range, you could do something like:

```
for ((i=2; i<=$# - 1; i++))
```

Also, if you want the last param: `${!#}`

Comment: Nice addition Dennis - just what I need now

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html#EX19), you need shift to step through positional parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
# Iterating through the provided arguments
for ARG in $*; do
    if [ -f filename_$ARG.txt]; then
        grep "$str" filename_$ARG.txt 
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
args=$@;args=${args// /,}
grep "foo" $(eval echo file{$args})
```